# NodeJS Electron - Uncaught Exception: TypeError: protocol.registerStandardSchemes is not a function

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to setup a penetration [tool](https://github.com/AntSwordProject/antSword) developed in NodeJS. There is an error when i run the NodeJS APP.

`*Uncaught Exception: TypeError: protocol.registerStandardSchemes is not a function at App.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/projects/antSword/app.js:26:12)*`

Following is the code of app.js File.

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const electron = require('electron');
const {
  app,
  shell,
  protocol,
  BrowserWindow
} = require('electron');

app.once('ready', () => {
  protocol.registerStandardSchemes(['ant-views', 'ant-static', 'ant-src']);
  [
    [
      'static', '/static/', 13
    ],
    [
      'views', '/views/', 12
    ], 
    ['src', '/source/', 10] 
  ].map((_) => {
    protocol.registerFileProtocol(`ant-${_[0]}`, (req, cb) => {
      if (req.url.endsWith('/')) {
        req.url = req
          .url
          .substr(0, req.url.length - 1);
      }
      cb({
        path: path.normalize(path.join(__dirname, _[1], req.url.substr(_[2])))
      });
    });
  });


});
```

I have already tried to fix it through different solution but found no luck.
Community's help in this regard will be highly appreciated.